# flex-container goes over the sibling container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-container which has an attribution div **as its sibling**-

[image]

I have set flex-container to `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` but the problem is that when it wraps, its items go over the attribution field-

[image]

I did try setting `display: block` to `attribution` field but it doesn't work. I also tried to set the parent container (`footer` ) to `display: flex`, which contains this `flex-container` and `attribution`field, to make `attribution` a flex item, but still it doesn't work.

When I hover over the container in debug tools, I see that the size has not changed but the flex-items have overflown.

[image]

Could you help me seek out the problem?

```css
#footer {
    padding: 5% 10%;
    background: getColor(light-gray-bg);
}
.references {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        gap: 20%;
}
.references div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2vh;
}

.references h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    color: getColor(dark-grayish-violet);
}

.references a {
     font-size: 0.9em;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: gray;
}
.attribution {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 3vh;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
}
.attribution a {
    color: #a33e70;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">

        <!-- References -->
        <section class="references">
            <div class="our-company">
                <h6>Our company</h6>
                
                <a href="#">How we work</a>
                <a href="#">Why Insure?</a>
                <a href="#">View plans</a>
                <a href="#">Reviews</a>
            </div>

            <div class="help-me">
                <h6>Help me</h6>
                
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                <a href="#">Terms of use</a>
                <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
                <a hred="#">Cookies</a>
            </div>

            <div class="contact">
                <h6>Contact</h6>
                
                <a href="#">Sales</a>
                <a href="#">Support</a>
                <a href="#">Live chat</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="others">
                <h6>Others</h6>
                
                <a href="#">Careers</a>
                <a href="#">Press</a>
                <a href="#">Licenses</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <div class="attribution">
            Challenge by <a     href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
            Coded by <a href="https://frontendmentor.io/profile/sapinder-pal">Sapinder</a>.
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Hi, the code snippet given cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's working I see! when I open it in full page and shrink the window, it does reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi, this is what is see from the code snippet in full-page and shrink the window. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/aEKp5PI.png)

Comment: then maybe something with vendor-prefixes? my browser is firefox.

Comment: I am using chrome. I can see the issue with firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215273/discussion-between-sapinder-and-yinsweet).

Comment: I have updated my finding and workaround for your issue.